# How to remove from django-tables2 a notation of the total row numbers in a pagination area

Tags: django, pagination, html-table, django-tables2

I cannot reproduce the same appearance of the table pagination format from the basic `django-tables2` [example](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html). Here is my code

**Model**:

```
#models.py
class Person(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(verbose_name="full name", max_length=200)
```

**Table**:

```
# tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables
from loaddata.models import Person

class PersonTable(tables.Table):
     class Meta:
          model = Person
          # add class="paleblue" to <table> tag
          attrs = {"class": "paleblue"}
```

**View**:

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_tables2   import RequestConfig
from loaddata.models  import Person
from loaddata.tables  import PersonTable

def people(request):
     table = PersonTable(Person.objects.all())
     RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 25}).configure(table)
     return render(request, "loaddata/people.html", {"table": table})
```

This code produces the following table (`#1`)

[image]

Whereas according to the [tutorial](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html), the table should look like this (`#2`)

[image]

As seen my table (`#1`) misses the current page number, but instead it shows the total number of data series (`2 persons`). However if the pagination `per_page` parameter in the `view` is changed to `1`, i.e.

**View** modified:

```
#views.py
...
     RequestConfig(request, paginate={"per_page": 1}).configure(table)
...
```

then my table (`#3`) will show the current paging and the redundant `1 of 2 persons`.

[image]

What should I change in the code to remove from the pagination area the total number of data series (get rid of `2 persons`, `1 of 2 persons`) and force the current page numbering be present even if the table has one page (i.e. make table `#1` the same as table `#2`)?

I am using:

- `python 3.4.3`
- `django 1.9`
- `django_tables2 1.1.6`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the default page template (for instance @ https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2/table.html) you'll see the following two blocks:

```
{% if table.page.has_previous or table.page.has_next %}
    {% block pagination.current %}
        <li class="current">
            {% blocktrans with table.page.number as current and table.paginator.num_pages as total %}Page {{ current }} of {{ total }}{% endblocktrans %}
        </li>
    {% endblock pagination.current %}
{% endif %}

....
{% block pagination.cardinality %}
    <li class="cardinality">
        {% if total != count %}{% blocktrans %}{{ count }} of {{ total }}{% endblocktrans %}{% else %}{{ total }}{% endif %} {% if total == 1 %}{{ table.data.verbose_name }}{% else %}{{ table.data.verbose_name_plural }}{% endif %}
    </li>
{% endblock pagination.cardinality %}
```

The first block checks if the table has more than one page an displays the page number - so you should remove the check if you want to always display the page number. The other block displays the amount of items - so you could just dump it.

Now, to override the table template there are two ways:

- Override the table template globally for all django-tables2 tables on your site: In on of your apps (or your global templates directory) add a file named `django_tables2/table.html` and copy there the table.html from the source of django_tables2 - with the mentioned above edits of course. Then all your tables will use the new template.
- Override just one template: Copy the table.html source I mentioned above somewhere with a different name (for example `mytable.html`) and then use that template to render your table by passing it ot the template tag, something like `{% render table "mytable.html" %}` (https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/template-tags.html#render-table)

Comment: I've just overriden table using this template (which you've written above) and I realized that there is no "count" in the template. There is a 
{% with table.page.object_list|length as count %} but the count variable isn't used anywhere (which OP wants but this is a general template so there should be count). Is it a bug?